# OpenGL Trying to translate object, but the camera also translates, which I don't need

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, translation

I am trying to translate a cloud texture. However, the camera also translates that way, what I don't want. So just moving clouds, nothing else moving.

How I translate the clouds:

```
MatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "MVP");
transID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "transformation");

glm::mat4 translate = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.f), glm::vec3(cloudTranslation, 0.0f, 0.0f));
glUniformMatrix4fv(transID, 1, GL_FALSE, 
glm::value_ptr(translate));
cloudTranslation += 1.0f;
```

Vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 uvVerts;

out vec2 uv;

uniform mat4 MVP;
uniform mat4 transformation;

void main(){
    gl_Position =  MVP * transformation * vec4(position,1);
    uv = uvVerts;
}
```

I hope anyone can see the problem.

**Note:
Yes, I multiplied the MVP(modelviewprojection matrix) with the transformation matrix, because otherwise I didnt know how to even move the clouds.**

I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're after. The obvious solution is that you only set the translation when you're rendering the clouds, and reset it while rendering everything else. Is there anything more to it?

Comment: But how to set the translation without translating the rest?

Comment: You reset it by calling `glUniformMatrix4fv` with a different matrix.

Comment: Okay, isn't there a more comfortable way to do this? I think it's very line wasting to reset the uniform variable everytime.

Comment: @PythonLover17 ... You have a transformation matrix for the clouds, and one for everything else. You render the clouds with the cloud matrix, and everything else with the everything else matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I fixed it, I forgot to multiply the matrices of MVP matrix...